# Monitor new packages in installed repositories?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management

I'd like to know which new packages (brand new, not the updated ones) have appeared in my installed repos. Just in case there can be something useful :)

I guess it should be a simple bash script to list-sort-diff. But maybe, there're some better solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Aptitude](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aptitude) [image] has a section for “New packages”, listing all the packages that appeared since you last cleared the list. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to clear the list.

Comment: @Gareth `http://bit.ly/software-small` is standard usage on [ubuntu.se]. [The image is broken for some people](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1852/software-centre-image-link-is-broken), but no solution has been found so far.